# How do I load detail content when row/ column is clicked

Tags: kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm practicing Jetpack Compose, I'm trying to create a screen that load texts and image content when navigated to.

Here's what I mean;

[image: Android Developers Soothe App Home Image]

[Referencing the android developer soothe app.] If I make the rows clickable. And I want to navigate to a screen containing details of Inversions, quick yoga or stretching, depending on which is clicked.

What compose navigation feature should I use to create it??

I did a bit of research previously but I haven't been able to find what I need.

Just in case it's needed, I'll add these.

my compose navigation version;

```
    def nav_version = "2.5.2"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"
```

I'll be sinerely greatful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to navigate to a seperate screen when you click one of the items inside the Horizontal LazyRow. In order to do this you will need to implement navigation using compose navigation library: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation
and you will need to add an onClick event for each item in that LazyRow. For this you would need to set up a NavController, Navhost and Routes for each item.

I have set up something similar but with a navigation Drawer, maybe it will help you understand how the navigation works in jetpack compose!
[Navigating between composable's using a Navigation Drawer in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921484/navigating-between-composables-using-a-navigation-drawer-in-jetpack-compose)

Hope this will help you!